XtaCache service blocks x86_64 process dependencies after process closed on Windows
Third party application build for x86_64 arch and run on Windows arm.
After process closed(CreateToolhelp32Snapshot returns list without application name and GetExitCode return 0), tring to replace application dependencies(.dll build for x86_64) but get "Access denied" and using system rstrtmgr library got that XtaCache blocks dependencies, reproduced not in 100% cases, expecting that xtacache release process dependencies after process closed, anybody faced with similar issue or maybe there is a workaround?
